# Google map marker infoWindows close event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

I tried show a alert when infowindow closed.
I get this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined

```
 (function (marker, data){
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
  //alert("clicked marker");  it is working.

  });

  google.maps.evet.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function () {
 //alert("closed"); it is not working.
   });

  })
```

Comment: typo: `google.maps.evet.addListener` should be `google.maps.event.addListener` (`google.maps.evet` is not defined)

Comment: Yes you are right.It is my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very simple mistake.Sorry for this question.

google.maps.**evet**.addListener <- change to -> google.maps.**event**.addListener